# Building point cloud using input from position, orientation and laser scan data

Tags: pose, pcl, pointcloud, ros-pcl, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am willing to build a point cloud taking input from position and
orientation (pose message) data gathered over time along with laser scan
message. In achieving this, of course I need to publish a topic of type PointCloud, but, then, the processing procedures, I'm not really sure.

The stored pose data looks like below:

Here is a loop of the data gathered reading some values row by row..

```
{btQuaternion q(pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][8]), pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][7]),
pcl::deg2rad(data_set[t][6]));

        pose3D.position.x =  data_set[t][3];
        pose3D.position.y = data_set[t][4];
        pose3D.position.z = data_set[t][5];

        pose3D.orientation.x = q.x();
        pose3D.orientation.y = q.y();
        pose3D.orientation.z = q.z();
        pose3D.orientation.w = q.w();
}
```

Could someone provide me any code snippet or example that does the
functionality.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12369/building-point-cloud-using-input-from-position,-orientation-and-laser-scan-data/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS provides the [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) package to do just this. Give that a shot. It will make your life much easier.

**Edit**: Here's some code to publish your odom information. You would publish this at a certain interval in your odometry node, and laser_geometry would be able to read it.

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(pose3D.position.x, pose3D.position.y, pose3D.position.z));
tf::Quaternion qt(pose3D.orientation.x, pose3D.orientation.y, pose3D.orientation.z, pose3D.orientation.w);
xform.setRotation(qt);
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time::now(), "base_frame", "target_frame"));
```

For more information, check the [tf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
@DimitriProsser:  Thanks a lot, that one works..however, when I check for the Point Cloud2, it complaints "Showing [0] points from [0] messages" even, when I check for /laser, there are messages got published..

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-16**:
Try what I've posted above.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
I've tried "    xform.setRotation(pose3D.orientation.x, pose3D.orientation.y, pose3D.orientation.z, pose3D.orientation.w);", it doesn't work either.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
But it complaints in the line "xform.setRotation(pose3D.orientation); " , is that parameter enough?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-16**:
The code snippet already does that. Whoever has this information needs to fill the pose3D struct and call this code.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
What do you mean by this "You would publish this at a certain interval"? How do we do this?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
@DimitriProsser: Thanks for the code snippet, but it complaints on "xform.setRotation(pose3D.orientation);
" , is that parameter enough?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
@dornhege:how do I assign/relate this pose message with the tf?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-16**:
tf

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-16**:
With regard to this laser_geometry package, where does my pose information come into play?